# How to read button touches in table?

Tags: android, button, touch

What's the correct way to test for button touches in a table of buttons (custom keypad)? OnTouch Listeners for every button seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not cumbersome. However I would suggest using the same listener for all of them. *(And this is using `OnTouchListener`; `OnClickListener` may be better in your case.)*

```
public class MyButtonTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
        Button b = (Button) v;
        String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
        // Do whatever, based on buttonText. Example: if (buttonText.equals("#")) { doPound(); }
    }
}
```

Then, you create one of these items, and assign it to all of them.

```
MyButtonTouchListener listener = new MyButtonTouchListener();
ArrayList<Button> myButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
// Add all your Button objects to the ArrayList.
for (Button b : myButtons)
    b.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Now, your listener only appears once in memory, and each item still has unique functionality.

Comment: That's what I was thinking - a discrete touch listener for every button was cumbersome and there must be a proper way to collect them into one bit of code. ;) Thanks.